# Infinite amount of unique generated variables, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop, user-input

So, I'm making a program that asks for user input to define a variable. What I want it to do is keep prompting them to define variables until they terminate the program. I.E. it prompts A1: and they input 2, and then it Prompts A2: and they input 6, and so on, until they press enter without inputting anything. The problem I am having is that I need unique variables for each time it loops. I also want these variables to be able to access the variables defined outside of the function, without using global.

Here is what I've got:

```
def userinput():
    n = 0
    while n >= 0:
        c = str(n)
        v = 'A'+c+':'
        v = input(v)
        if v != '':
            n += 1
        else:
            while v == '':
                break
            break
userinput()
```

As you can see, what it does know is set the user's input equal to **v** each iteration. I want it to set the first input to A0, then the next iteration, I want it the input to be set to A1, and so on and so forth. Then, after the user has run this, I want to be able to call the variable A1 and get a result. Any ideas?

EDIT:
So, here is my program. It takes input, adds the input to a list, then converts the list items to global variables. I didn't want to use global, but I had to.

```
def userinput():
    n = 0
    values = []
    while True:
        c = str(n)
        v = 'A'+c+':'
        v = input(v)
        values.append(v)
        if v != '':
            n += 1
        else:
            while v == '':
                values.remove(v)
                break
            break
    for x, val in enumerate(values):
        globals()['A%d' % (x)] = val
    return values
data = userinput()
```

Comment: Use a container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list?

```
def getUserInput():
  values = []
  while True:
    val = input("Enter a value (press enter to finish):")
    if not val:
      break
    values.append(val)
  return values

data = getUserInput()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a while loop, make a for loop wrapped in a while loop, like this:

```
def userinput():
n = 0
while n >= 0:
    for x in range(100):
        v = 'A'+x+':'
        v = input(v)
        if v != '':
            n += 1
        else:
            while v == '':
                break
            break
userinput()
```

Comment: this doesn't break at the end, it just returns to asking for A0

Answer (score 0):

Once again, here is the answer:

```
def userinput():
    n = 0
    values = []
    while True:
        c = str(n)
        v = 'A'+c+':'
        v = input(v)
        values.append(v)
        if v != '':
            n += 1
        else:
            while v == '':
                values.remove(v)
                break
            break
    for x, val in enumerate(values):
        globals()['A%d' % (x)] = val
    return values
data = userinput()
```